# Jquery: trigger function after another is complete

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a loading gif that appears on all pages of my rails app and fades out once the page is fully loaded:

**application.html.erb**

```
$(window).load(function(){

    // remove loading animation
    if($('#loading').css('display')!='none'){
        $('#loading').fadeOut(400, function(){
           $('#main').animate({opacity:1});
    });
    }
```

On certain pages, I want to make sure things don't get triggered until after the loading icon has already faded out.  For example, when I load a project page, I want to scroll to the middle of the page once the loading icon has completed so the user sees the scrolling animation.

**project/index.html.erb**

```
   $('.projectView').animate({scrollTop: $('.question_accordion').position().top});
```

**I can't chain it directly to the loading fadeOut because the loading fadeOut appears on every page, and I only need it to scroll only on the step index page.  Whatever I do MUST be part of the project/index.html.erb file, not application.html.erb**

How can I trigger javascript code only after another has completed (and in a separate function)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a done callback to the fx queue promise object for the loading element.

```
// to ensure we run this right after the fadeOut is started
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#loading").promise().done(function(){
        $('.projectView').animate({scrollTop: $('.question_accordion').position().top});
    });
});
```

Comment: didn't know about promise; this worked for me with some extra added timeouts!